# Ошибка при ответе на команду start ,telegram bot, Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Файл запускается, но после ввода в чат команды `start` вылетает ошибка. Не могу ее понять, подскажите пожалуйста.
Ошибка будет после кода

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher

from aiogram.types import Message
import markups as nav
import asyncio

token = 'token'


async def get_start(message:Message, bot: Bot):
    await message.answer(f'<b>Привет {message.from_user.first_name}. Рады приветствовать тебя в нашем магазине!</b>',parse_mode="html", reply_markup= nav.mainMenu)


async def start():
    bot = Bot(token = token)


    dp = Dispatcher(bot)
    dp.register_message_handler(get_start)
    try:
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    finally:
        await dp.session.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(start())
```

> > Task exception was never retrieved
> > future: <Task finished name='Task-16' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\kvard\PycharmProjects\TechItBot_test\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=TypeError("get_start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bot'")>
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > TypeError: get_start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bot'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибка в том что в get_start, аргумент bot обязательный, можете либо сделать его необязательным либо передать туда значение
Вообще не вижу чтобы этот аргумент где-то использовался, поэтому его вообще стоит убрать
Попробуйте так:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher

from aiogram.types import Message
import markups as nav
import asyncio
from aiogram.filters.command import Command

token = 'token'
bot = Bot(token=token)
# Диспетчер
dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def get_start(message:Message):
    await message.answer(f'<b>Привет {message.from_user.first_name}. Рады приветствовать тебя в нашем магазине!</b>',
                         parse_mode="html", reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)


async def start():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(start())
```

PS. Не оставляйте токен от бота в открытом доступе, его могут угнать

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: спасибо убрал токен, надеюсь никто не успел воспользоваться

Comment: Если мой ответ, помог разобраться с проблемой, пометите его как решение пожалуйста